# Rails 5, Rolify - Role Assignment Strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rolify

I am not very good at learning how to code. I've been trying for 4 years and still struggling to figure out basic concepts.

I haven't found the right starting point so, I'm constantly gap filling for things that might be foundations and I don't know them yet.

I have a Rails 5 app. It has models for user, roles, app_roles and assign_roles.

The associations are:

User

```
rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
  attr_accessor :current_role
belongs_to :organisation
```

Role

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true
```

AppRole

[no associations]
Note: this is the resource I'm using to have a CRUD to define roles that the app can use to assign roles to users.

Assign Role

[no associations]
Note: this is the resource I'm using to allow some users to assign roles to some other users.

Organisation

```
has_many :users
```

I'm using rolify gem.

My user model has:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  rolify strict: true # strict means you get true only on a role that you manually add
  attr_accessor :current_role
```

My Roles table has:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles

  belongs_to :resource,
             :polymorphic => true,
             :optional => true

  validates :resource_type,
            :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
            :allow_nil => true

  scopify
end
```

In my assign_roles controller,  I have:

```
  class Users::AssignRolesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    # if @current_user.is_admin?
      @app_roles = AppRole.all
    # else
    #   @app_roles = AppRole.where(category: relevant_category)
    # end

    # if @current_user.is_admin?
        @users = User.all
   #  else 
      #   @users = current_user.organisation.users.select { |u| u.id != current_user.organisation.owner_id }
    # end  
  end


  def create
    user = User.find(params[:users])
    role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    # @organisation = Organisation.find(@current_user.organisation)
     # byebug

    user.add_role role.display_name, @current_user.organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

  def show
    # @users = User.joins(:profiles).where('profiles.organisation_id = ?' @current_user.organisation.id)
    # @users = User.all
    @current_user.organisation.users
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy

    user = User.find(params[:users])
    # role = AppRole.find(params[:roles])
    assigned_role = user.roles
    # user_roles = user.roles
    # organisation = Organisation.first
    # byebug

    user.remove_role assigned_role.name, @current_user.organisation

    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created"
    redirect_to action: :index
  end

end
```

In my routes file, i have:

```
resources :users, shallow: true do
    scope module: :users do
      resources :assign_roles
      resources :identities
    end
  end
```

In my views/users/assign_roles/index file, I have:

```
<%= form_tag(url: '/assign_roles', method: :post ) do |f| %>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom: 150px">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
       <%= select_tag "users", options_from_collection_for_select(@users, "id", "full_name"), { class: "chosen-select form-control" } %>
    </div>

                        <!-- # roles -->

    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= select_tag "roles", options_from_collection_for_select(@app_roles, "id", "display_name"), :class => 'chosen-select form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= submit_tag(value = "Submit") %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

So far, that all looks OK. Im' getting stuck at the next part.

In my views/users/assign_roles/show.html.er

I'm trying to show each user's roles on a view. I want the user that assigned any existing roles to be able to delete them.

I have:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>

      <td><%= user.roles.count %></td>
       <% user.roles.each do |role| %>
           <td><%= role.name.titleize %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', role, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
         <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

My controller for assign_roles is saved in app/controllers/users folder. My views folder for assign roles is saved inside app/views/users/assign_roles

When I try to use the app/users/4/assign_roles form, I get the form to render with the list of AppRoles that are available to be assigned. I don't get any error message. Instead, I get the notice on successful creation. However, when I try to check if a user has a role, I get false.

I can see the server log reads as follows:

```
Started POST "/users/4/assign_roles?method=post&url=%2Fassign_roles" for ::1 at 2016-10-23 11:50:11 +1100
Processing by Users::AssignRolesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U80gMQd01SaTcHHnnSFxvRc2u9JvJMFB+5smS9SaN8ZRixQvJRTMbutG0KkoqXL+oMU1aOxX8AURBtuy2Rm5yA==", "users"=>"4", "roles"=>"3", "commit"=>"Submit", "method"=>"post", "url"=>"/assign_roles", "user_id"=>"4"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  AppRole Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "app_roles".* FROM "app_roles" WHERE "app_roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organisation Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations" ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Role Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = $1 AND "roles"."resource_type" = $2 AND "roles"."resource_id" = $3 ORDER BY "roles"."id" ASC LIMIT $4  [["name", "sdfddd"], ["resource_type", "Organisation"], ["resource_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  HABTM_Roles Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users_roles".* FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 4]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.5ms)  SELECT "roles".id FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 4]]
  Role Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = 1
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 4]]
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/4/assign_roles
Completed 302 Found in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 6.5ms)
```

I don't know what the ROLLBACK line means but I don't think that usually appears in these log messages when things are working correctly.

Can anyone see what I need to do to get the role assignment working correctly?

**organisation model**

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord

  include LogoUploader[:logo]
  include BannerUploader[:banner]


  # --------------- associations

  has_many :users

  # --------------- scopes




  # --------------- validations


  # --------------- class methods

  enum org_type: {
                    University: 1,
                    Publicly_Funded_Research_Organisation: 2,
                    Industry: 3,
                    Grantor: 4,
                    Investor: 5,
                    Policy: 6,

                  }



  # --------------- callbacks

  # --------------- instance methods

  # --------------- private methods



end
```

Comment: what is your `rolify` version?

Comment: @Nikhil rolify-5.1.0

Comment: can you paste the result of `r = Role.new(name: 'admin')` then `r.valid?` and then `r.errors.messages` in rails console

Comment: 2.3.1p112 :042 > r = Role.new(name: 'admin')
 => #<Role id: nil, name: "admin", resource_type: nil, resource_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.3.1p112 :043 > r.valid?
 => true 
2.3.1p112 :044 > r.errors.messages
 => {} 
2.3.1p112 :045 >

Comment: please add the `organisation` model definition in question

Comment: add `resourcify` to your `organisation` model and then try like https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify#32-configure-your-resource-models

Comment: any luck with resourcify?

Comment: Thanks very much. That worked

Comment: I am adding my comment as answer. Please upvote and award. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `resourcify` to your organisation model and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of developing our own RBAC (Role Based Access Control), there are already some open source gems available in rails community. we can make use of that.

Its a nice gem

> https://github.com/nathanl/authority

Also there are many other gems available

> https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization

If none of the above gems fulfil your need, then atleast you can use that as an sample model for your development.

Comment: @Sivalingham - i'm using pundit for authorisations, but I'm trying to authorise based on roles. Thanks for the tips.